Magnetic energy associated with an intrinsic dipole
Generally for an Amperian dipole we have:

Magnetic energy when it is placed in a uniform magnetic field is $\vec m \cdot \vec B$.


We can define "a fake kind of energy" [Feynman] that can be used to find forces: $-\vec m \cdot \vec B$. (To use earlier formula we would have to also account for change in $\vec m$ when we rotate it, work done by source, work done by ext agent etc., i.e., account for all energies; while in this formula we merely figure out an energy corresponding to the magnetic force on a wire backwards.)

I always thought of energy as being stored in the fields. However in all reputed books I have read, they say,

Magnetic energy corresponding to intrinsic dipoles placed in a uniform magnetic field is $\mathbf{-}\vec m \cdot \vec B$.

One could think that there's some energy associated with intrinsic structure that makes "real energy" equal to "fake energy for Amperian dipoles". But this is not possible because the difference between the two depends on $\vec B$ that we are supplying?
Where is this extra energy stored if it can't be there in the magnetic field (identical in both cases)?

Perhaps you should first look at the simpler case of a charge in an $E$-field. In any case you'll have to solve the infinity problem of the field around a point charge or point dipole (by choosing a finite-size distribution) and then do some partial integration with gradients and Laplace operators to see that both definitions are compatible.
